# How do you add an index field to Linq SelectMany results

Tags: c#, lambda

i have a simple SelectMany

```
List<string> animal = new List<string>() { "cat", "dog", "donkey" };
List<int> number = new List<int>() { 10, 20 };
var result = number.SelectMany((num, index) => animal, (n, a) => index + n + a );

// expected result: 0cat10, 1dog10, 2donkey10, 3cat20, 4dog20, 5donkey20
```

i want to add a index but i can't figure out the right syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<string> animals = new List<string> { "cat", "dog", "donkey" };
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 10, 20 };
var output = numbers.SelectMany(n => animals.Select(s => s + n))
                    .Select((g,i) => i + g);
```

You can do with single `SelectMany`, but it won't be that nice:

```
List<string> animals = new List<string> { "cat", "dog", "donkey" };
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 10, 20 };
var output = numbers.SelectMany((n,ni) => animals.Select((s,si) => ((ni * animals.Count) + si) + s + n))
```

Comment: nice one. i guess there is no way to put it all into the SelectMany?

Comment: @fubo GreenEyedAndy proposed the way with single SelectMany

Comment: @fubo I added the solution with single `SelectMany`, but it doesn't look nice

Answer (score 1):

Put the index out of the SelectMany:

```
List<string> animal = new List<string>() { "cat", "dog", "donkey" };
List<int> number = new List<int>() { 10, 20 };
var index = 0;
var result = number.SelectMany(n => animal, (n, a) => index++ + a + n );
```